# What are the "remote writes" which you can await with CU_STREAM_WAIT_VALUE_FLUSH?

Tags: memory, cuda, synchronization, cuda-driver

When you perform a wait-on-value operation using the CUDA driver API call `cuStreamWaitValue32()`, you can specify the flag `CU_STREAM_WAIT_VALUE_FLUSH`. Here's what the documentation [says](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEMOP.html#group__CUDA__MEMOP) it does:

> Follow the wait operation with a flush of outstanding remote writes. This
> means that, if a remote write operation is guaranteed to have reached the
> device before the wait can be satisfied, that write is guaranteed to be
> visible to downstream device work.

My question is: What counts as a "remote write" in this context? Is it only calls to `cuStreamWriteValue32()` /  `cuStreamWriteValue64()`? Is it any kind of write involving a different device or the host? Including `cudaMemcpy()` and friends?

Answer (score 1):

Remote Writes are writes issued by a third party device targeting the GPU device memory. This is related to [GPUDirect RDMA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html).
By extension, that also includes writes by issued by the CPU via [GDRCopy](https://github.com/NVIDIA/gdrcopy) mappings.

Comment: Is this your common-sense reading of the definition, or do you have an "official basis" for this answer?